# Getting Data from the Frontend & CORS

Tags: javascript, django, api

i´m stuck at a little demo project from udemy with django and api calls. I have this in main.js and I want to get array of object and not just a json list in console.

```
let projectsUrl = 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/projects/'

let getProjects = () => {
   
    fetch(projectsUrl)
        .then(response => response.json())
        .then(data => {
            console.log(data)
            buildProjects(data)
        })
   
}

let buildProjects = (projects) => {
    
    let projectsWrapper = document.getElementById('testz')

    for (let i = 0; projects.lenght > i; i++){
        let project = projects[i]
        console.log(project)
    }
}


getProjects()
```

The result :

[Console Log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Btdml.jpg)

and the result should be something like this :

[Console Log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7kWCe.jpg)

Comment: Need to provide the contents of the JSON file to see what's in that file. Also, there's a typo in the for loop. It should be "projects.length" not "projects.lenght"

Answer (score 2):

There is a typo.

change

```
projects.lenght
```

to

```
projects.length
```

Comment: Thank you Yasin, I was literally staring 2 hours at my monitor for a typo error.